# Draw bloxplots in R given 25,50,75 percentiles and min and max values

Tags: r, boxplot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [geom_boxplot with precomputed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628847/geom-boxplot-with-precomputed-values)

I have a table where each row is a different sample and each column is the name, minimum, maximum, mean, 25th percentile, 50th percentile, 75th percentile respectively. Here is a sample.

```
sample1   1   38   10   8    10   13
sample2   1   39   10   9    11   14
sample3   2   36   11   10   10   13
```

I would like to know how I can use the data in this format in order to plot boxplots since that is the data that is actually plotted. The format above is a tab separated table. Thanks

Comment: @joran thanks for pointing that out, I will check the post you mention and if so I'll close this one.

Comment: @GSee's comment has vanished, but was a good point. The `boxplot` base function also accepts precomputed values as well I believe, but I couldn't find a question on SO directly dealing with that function.

Comment: @joran From that post it was unclear to me how I could input data from the tsv format. My table has many more samples so it would be tough to input the data like that.

Comment: So if, as it seems, you don't know how to read data from a file into R, that seems like a separate, and very different question than "how do I make a boxplot with pre computed values".

Comment: When I posted I had no idea how to how do I make a boxplot with pre computed values. Now I have an idea of how to do it inputing manually the data, and I guess now I have a problem translating from the read.tsv to the data.frame. I will edit my question

Comment: Please don't change the very nature of your question. It renders current answers and comments nonsensical. Now that you know how to make boxplots with precomputed values, if you run into specific problems implementing that solution, ask a separate question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/27690/is-it-possible-to-plot-a-boxplot-from-previously-calculated-statistics-easily-i) shows how you can do this with `bxp` which is the function that `boxplot` uses, but you need to put your data in the right order with the first row being the minimum, and the last row being the maximum.

First, read in the data

```
dat <- read.table(text="sample1   1   38   10   8    10   13
sample2   1   39   10   9    11   14
sample3   2   36   11   10   10   13", row.names=1, header=FALSE)
```

Then, put in order and `t`ranspose

```
dat2 <- t(dat[, c(1, 4, 5, 6, 2)]) #Min, 25pct, 50pct, 75pct, Max
```

and plot

```
bxp(list(stats=dat2, n=rep(10, ncol(dat2)))) #n is the number of observations in each group
```

Comment: In the last line in n=rep(10,3), 3 is the number of samples, so what is 10?

Comment: 3 is the number of groups. 10 is the number of observations in each group, and it's just a guess.  How many observations did sample1 have?

Comment: I don't think it matters here.  You could make it `n=rep(1, 3)` if you wanted

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate, however for posterity and since I already started writing...

```
dat <- data.frame(name=paste0('sample',1:3), min=c(1,1,2), max=c(38,39,36), mean=c(10,10,11), q25=c(8,9,10), q50=c(10,11,10), q75=c(13,14,13))

ggplot(dat, aes(x=name, ymin=min, ymax=max, lower=q25, middle=q50, upper=q75))+geom_boxplot(stat='identity')
```

Comment: how can I input the data from the tsv?