# boxplot using precalculated (summary) statistics

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

I need to do a boxplot (in Python and matplotlib) but I do not have the original "raw" data.
What I have are precalculated values for max, min, mean, median and IQR (normal distribution) but still I'd like to do a boxplot. Of course plotting outliers isn't possible, but beside that I guess all information is there.

I've search all over to find an answer without success. The closest I've come is the same question but for R (which I'm unfamiliar with). See [Is it possible to plot a boxplot from previously-calculated statistics easily (in R?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952819/is-it-possible-to-plot-a-boxplot-from-previously-calculated-statistics-easily-i)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the old versions, you have to manually do it by changing boxplot elements individually:

```
Mean=[3.4] #mean
IQR=[3.0,3.9] #inter quantile range
CL=[2.0,5.0] #confidence limit
A=np.random.random(50)
D=plt.boxplot(A) # a simple case with just one variable to boxplot
D['medians'][0].set_ydata(Mean)
D['boxes'][0]._xy[[0,1,4], 1]=IQR[0]
D['boxes'][0]._xy[[2,3],1]=IQR[1]
D['whiskers'][0].set_ydata(np.array([IQR[0], CL[0]]))
D['whiskers'][1].set_ydata(np.array([IQR[1], CL[1]]))
D['caps'][0].set_ydata(np.array([CL[0], CL[0]]))
D['caps'][1].set_ydata(np.array([CL[1], CL[1]]))
_=plt.ylim(np.array(CL)+[-0.1*np.ptp(CL), 0.1*np.ptp(CL)]) #reset the limit
```

[image]

Comment: For people stumbling upon this and despairing about the syntax: There are easier ways to do this now, see the matplotlib documentation: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/bxp.html

Answer (score 21):

Thanks to the comment of @tacaswell I was able to find the required documentation and come up with an example using Matplotlib 1.4.3.
However, this example does not automatically scale the figure to the correct size.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

item = {}

item["label"] = 'box' # not required
item["mean"] = 5 # not required
item["med"] = 5.5
item["q1"] = 3.5
item["q3"] = 7.5
#item["cilo"] = 5.3 # not required
#item["cihi"] = 5.7 # not required
item["whislo"] = 2.0 # required
item["whishi"] = 8.0 # required
item["fliers"] = [] # required if showfliers=True

stats = [item]

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 1)
axes.bxp(stats)
axes.set_title('Default')
y_axis = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
y_values = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
plt.yticks(y_axis, y_values)
```

Relevant links to the documentation:

- [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html)
- [boxplot_stats datastructure](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/cbook_api.html#matplotlib.cbook.boxplot_stats)
- [Boxplot drawer function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/statistics/bxp.html)

Answer (score 9):

Referring to the answer of @MKroehnert and `Boxplot drawer function` at https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/bxp.html, the following could be helpful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

stats = [{
    "label": 'A',  # not required
    "mean":  5,  # not required
    "med": 5.5,
    "q1": 3.5,
    "q3": 7.5,
    # "cilo": 5.3 # not required
    # "cihi": 5.7 # not required
    "whislo": 2.0,  # required
    "whishi": 8.0,  # required
    "fliers": []  # required if showfliers=True
    }]

fs = 10  # fontsize

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, figsize=(6, 6), sharey=True)
axes.bxp(stats)
axes.set_title('Boxplot for precalculated statistics', fontsize=fs)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Just wanted to add to this brilliant answer, if you want to plot multiple boxplots after using a `for` loop to append multiple `stats` to a `list` e.g. (before loop: `final_data = list()`, within but end of loop: `final_data.append(stats)`) to then plot them all on one figure, remove the `[]` around the `stats` dictionary in this answer. Probably a simple solution but took me a few minutes to figure that out.