# Box plot from binned data in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, boxplot, date-histogram

I would like to create a box plot from some pre-counted data (a histogram, essentially).  Is it possible to do this in Python?

I am using matplotlib and I noticed that the [boxplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot) function does not have something similar to the *weights* parameter of the [hist](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) function.

Comment: Read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Are you thinking of using wider boxes in your box plot to represent the histogram frequency?

Comment: @zhqiat I'm not sure I understand your question.  The use-case is that I want to plot multiple such box plots in the same figure, so the advantage is that they are a more compact representation of the distribution.

Comment: I don't think this question is understandable. Please consider giving an example of what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35325221/3183129).  The function I was looking for is [bxp](http://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bxp).  This question asks how to create a box plot when only having access to the summary statistics, which is an even more compact version of my original issue: I can easily compute those statistics from my pre-counted data.