# How to use boxplot to plot data like KEY / VALUE / COUNT-OBSERVATIONS?

Tags: r, boxplot, large-data

I've got a large file that looks like this:

```
SAMPLE1 10
SAMPLE1 10
SAMPLE1 10
SAMPLE1 2
SAMPLE2 10
SAMPLE2 10
SAMPLE2 2
SAMPLE2 2
```

the file is huge (several gigabytes) and R is killed when I want to read the file and then use`boxplot`. So my idea is to use `sort | uniq -c` on my file and to use a much smaller file that would now look like this ( with a 3rd column containing the number of observations):

```
SAMPLE1 10 3
SAMPLE1 2 1
SAMPLE2 10 2
SAMPLE2 2 2
```

Is there a way to use `base:boxplot` to plot such data ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a package `ENmisc` with a function `wtd.boxplot`.
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ENmisc/versions/1.2-7/topics/wtd.boxplot

Alternatively, calculate the weighted quartiles and then draw the boxplot using those values.

Answer (score 1):

We can pre-compute 5 numbers per sample (min, low, mid, upper, max) in *bash*. Then data would be small enough to import to *R*, then we can boxplot using summary data:

- [base: bxp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11952819/680068)
- [ggplot: geom_boxplot(stat = "identity")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10628847/680068)

Comment: User Miller (`mlr`) to compute the quartiles: https://miller.readthedocs.io/