# Generate Box Plot From 5 Number Summary (Min,Max,Quantiles)?

Tags: python, seaborn

Some researchers often report results in form of 5 number summary. While for my methodology I have raw data, I would like to compare box plots.

Hence, is it possible to draw boxplot from 5 number summary using matplotlib/seaborn?

The idea has already been discussed for R [here] and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129432/draw-bloxplots-in-r-given-25-50-75-percentiles-and-min-and-max-values)[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10628847/geom-boxplot-with-precomputed-values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 5 number summary could be seen as a dataset of 5 numbers: `[min, Q1, Q2, Q3, max]`.  Therefore, you can generate a dataset with these 5 numbers and plot them in a boxplot.

For example:

```
import seaborn

def fiveNumBox(mi, q1, q2, q3, ma):
    data = [mi, q1, q2, q3, ma]
    ax = seaborn.boxplot(data=data, orient="h")
    ax.get_figure().savefig('figure.png')

fiveNumBox(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Generates:
[image]