# R plot boxplot per column in dataframe and customizing parameters

Tags: r, boxplot

I have an R dataframe with 20 columns, one for each model. The lines of the dataset present the statistics for a boxplot. I want to plot a boxplot for each of those models, setting the parameters of the boxplot as the lines of the dataframe

Below is one example:

```
        Model 1    Model 2   ...  Model 20
min       1           5              15
q25       2           7              16
median    3           8              20
q75       4           9              21
max       5           10             22
```

As can be seeing, the statistics are already calculated. I just need to set them to the boxplot but I have no idea in how to do that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Draw bloxplots in R given 25,50,75 percentiles and min and max values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11129432/draw-bloxplots-in-r-given-25-50-75-percentiles-and-min-and-max-values)

Comment: Curious, how did you calculate those stats? If in R, run `boxplot` on that previous step.

Comment: @jpsmith I am having a weird behaviour. `bxp` expects a list. I pass a list and I receive an error: `Error in is.finite(z$stats) : default method not implemented for type 'list'`. I am literally using the same code as shown in question you sent and passing my df as a list to the `bxp`

Answer (score 0):

In case you are willing to use `ggplot2` you could try something like this:

Set up a fake dataset. Apparently, you need that to run `ggplot()` + `geom_boxplot()`:

```
df <- data.frame("Model" = "Model 1")
```

Then you can control the single boxplot components like this:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = Model,
           ymin=5,     #min
           lower=20,   #q25
           middle=25,  #median
           upper=50,   #q75
           ymax=100))+ #max
  geom_boxplot(stat="identity")
```

[image]

Analogous for multiple models:

```
df <- data.frame("Model" = c("Model 1", "Model 2"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = Model,
           ymin=c(5, 9),
           lower=c(20,46),
           middle=c(25,55),
           upper=c(50,89),
           ymax=c(100, 111)))+
  geom_boxplot(stat="identity")
```

Answer (score 0):

What has not been explained so far is that you need a matrix and not a data frame (since data frames are actually lists, the error refers to lists).  I assume you somewhere also have the sample sizes, I `rbind` them here as a new row.

```
dat <- rbind(dat, n=c(20, 14, 60))
```

So all you need to do is coercing `as.matrix`.

```
bxp(list(stats=as.matrix(dat[1:5, ]), n=dat[6, ]))
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='Model1    Model2   Model20
min       1           5              15
q25       2           7              16
median    3           8              20
q75       4           9              21
max       5           10             22')
```